# Update a partial view after changing password

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I don't know how to stay in the same page after changing the password inside a partial view. When i click the "Submit" button it takes me to another page, I would like to stay in the same page and only show a message like "password changing success" I Know the key is in

```
if (changePasswordSucceeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ChangePasswordSuccess");


            }
```

I've tried with

```
return Json(true)
```

but i don't know how to handle the result for just updating the page.

Thank you

UPDATE:
MAIN VIEW

```
@model Points2Pay.Models.Usuario
@using Points2Pay.Extensions;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Resources.Points2pay.Usuario_Tools2;
    ViewBag.Head = @Resources.Points2pay.Usuario_Tools2;
}

<h2>@Resources.Points2pay.Usuario_Head4</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Resources.Points2pay.Account_Text5</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UsuarioId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmailAlterno)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre) @Html.RequiredFieldFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Apellidos) @Html.RequiredFieldFor(model => model.Apellidos)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Apellidos)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Apellidos)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Direccion) @Html.RequiredFieldFor(model => model.Direccion)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Direccion)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Direccion)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pais) @Html.RequiredFieldFor(model => model.Pais)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pais)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pais)
        </div>

        @*<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAlterno)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAlterno)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAlterno)
        </div>*@

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telefono) @Html.RequiredFieldFor(model => model.Telefono)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telefono)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telefono)
        </div>

@*        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaAlta)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaAlta)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaAlta)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Estatus)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Estatus)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Estatus)
        </div>*@

@*        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Saldopublic)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Saldopublic)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Saldopublic)
        </div>*@

@*        <br />
           @Html.ActionLink(@Resources.Points2pay.ChangePassword, "ChangePassword", "Account", new { id = Model.UsuarioId }, null)
           <br />*@
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="@Resources.Points2pay.btn_Guardar" />
        </p>
    </fieldset> @Resources.Points2pay.CamposObligatorios <br />
}

<input type="submit" class="flip" value="@Resources.Points2pay.ChangePassword" />
<div class="panel">
@Html.Action("ChangePasswordPartial","Account")
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".panel").hide();
        $(".flip").click(function () {
            $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

PARTIAL VIEW

```
@model Points2Pay.Models.ChangePasswordModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Resources.Points2pay.ChangePassword;
    ViewBag.Head = Resources.Points2pay.ChangePassword;
}

<h2>@Resources.Points2pay.Account_Head1</h2>
<p>
    @Resources.Points2pay.Account_Text1 
</p>
<p>
    @Resources.Points2pay.Account_Text2 @Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength @Resources.Points2pay.Account_Text3
</p>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, @Resources.Points2pay.Account_Text4)
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>@Resources.Points2pay.Account_Text5</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OldPassword)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OldPassword)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassword)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPassword)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="@Resources.Points2pay.ChangePassword_Boton1" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).action,
                type: 'POST', //I'm assuming this could be type GET.
                data: $(this).serialize,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('ajax successfully');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

CONTROLLER

```
[Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather
                // than return false in certain failure scenarios.
                bool changePasswordSucceeded;
                try
                {
                    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true /* userIsOnline */);
                    changePasswordSucceeded = currentUser.ChangePassword(model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    changePasswordSucceeded = false;
                }

                if (changePasswordSucceeded)
                {
                    //return RedirectToAction("ChangePasswordSuccess");
                    return Json(true);


                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", Resources.Points2pay.Account_Error22);
                    //
                    //English
                    //ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="ShowResultHere"></div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { id="frmUpdate"}))
{
   //form fields
   <button type="submit" class="sprt bg_red bt_red h27">Update</button>
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(TestModel model)
{
   return Json(new { s = "Success" });
}

$(function() {
    $('#frmUpdate').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
               // The AJAX call succeeded and the server returned a JSON 
               // with a property "s" => we can use this property
               // and set the html of the target div
               $('#ShowResultHere').html(result.s);
            }
        });
        // it is important to return false in order to 
        // cancel the default submission of the form
        // and perform the AJAX call
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using button submit type you need to avoid the default behavior of your browser, in other words prevent the post back. To do that you need to called your action from your client with ajax, catch the event submit of the button and send the data. Assuming that you're using jquery something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.panel form').submit(function(e){
            $.ajax({
               url: $(this).action,
               type: 'POST' //I'm assuming this could be type GET.
               data: $(this).serialize,
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function(data){
                   alert('ajax successfully');
               }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: should I paste this in the partial view? or in the view that contains the partial view? I pasted it in the partial view but i seems that it didn't handle the json return because it only showed me a blank page with the word "true"

Comment: Add this in your partial View

Comment: Added a little change in the code see the update @FergieGauvain

Comment: It still doesn't work, after success it shows a blank page with the word "true"...

Comment: I forgot to sign the script with javascript, take a look again

Comment: after i hit the submit button it takes me to the partial view direction(http://localhost:56937/Account/ChangePassword) but only shows the word "true", I don´t know why the javascript doesn't catch the json

Comment: Muy bien... recuerda marcarla como aceptada y en caso de mi respuesta si te parecio de ayuda puedes colocar puntos

Comment: solo debes darle click a la flecha hacia arriba en la respuesta